# python strptime throws tuple index out of range

Tags: python, strptime

Using Redhat Python 2.7.5 I'm trying to parse a date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format using `datetime.datetime.strptime` and I intermitently get a tuple out of range error as follows:

```
client.py in parse_date(d='2014-12-05')
    138                 return dt.datetime.strptime(d,"%Y-%m-%d")
    139             except:
    140                 raise Exception("Unexpected Date: '{0}' ({1})".format(d), e)
undefined, d = '2014-12-05', e undefined
<type 'exceptions.IndexError'>: tuple index out of range 
args = ('tuple index out of range',) 
message = 'tuple index out of range'
```

That the format string looks correct, and the intermittent nature of the problem suggests some sort of threading issue, but to be honest I've no idea, nor any idea how to reliably reproduce the error.  Any suggestions to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I think is with the way you catch the exception:

```
except:
    raise Exception("Unexpected Date: '{0}' ({1})".format(d), e)
```

Here, you don't pass the variable `e` to `format` correctly. Instead, it should be

```
except:
    raise Exception("Unexpected Date: '{0}' ({1})".format(d, e))
```

Also, in case `e` happens to be the exception raise, you will need to explicitly get a variable as below:

```
except Exception as e:
    raise Exception("Unexpected Date: '{0}' ({1})".format(d), e)
```

Finally, it is better to capture the specific error which can be raised by the try block, so you should do

```
except ValueError as e:
    raise Exception("Unexpected Date: '{0}' ({1})".format(d), e)
```

Comment: Ok sorry yes: but why is the exception handler being reached anyway?

Comment: @user118165 Maybe because the date `d` is not always in the correct format? Or there might be some more code in the try block which raises the exception... Since you catch the generic `Exception`, and try to raise a new one instead, info about the the actual exception raised is lost.

Comment: @user118165: that will tell you the exception.

Comment: OK so for anyone who finds this, after I fixed the exception handler formatting I eventually tracked this down to a race condition in datetime, documented [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue7980).  The solution is to add an explicit `import _strptime` before any threads are kicked off.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So the Exception comes from your exception handler. Format has only one parameter, but uses two.